# Stopping animation when game is paused then resumed in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Based on research I've done on the internet, I came up with this code to pause and resume a game:

```
-(void)pauseGame:(UIApplication *)application{
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
//do other actions necessary}

-(void)resumeGame:(UIApplication *)application{
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
//do other actions}
```

This works fine but my problem is if the game is paused, closed then reopened. Normally, if you pause a game, then close it, when you open it, everything should still be paused. And after some research I ended up with this code in the Appdelegate:

```
-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application{
if( [navController_ visibleViewController] == director_ )
    [director_ stopAnimation];

RandomScene *s = [RandomScene node];
if(s.layer.gameStatus == FALSE)
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector]pause];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector]stopAnimation];
    [s.layer stopAllActions];
}}
```

With this code, when I reopen the game, the timer is still paused along with all touch events. However, my animation is still working, so my sprites are still moving when they're not supposed to. How can I stop the animation completely when the game is reopened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further research, I managed to find a solution to the problem I was having through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761735/how-to-pause-and-resume-in-cocos2d). I removed the CCDirector pause and resume in my pauseGame and resumeGame methods then added this:

```
//pause
[sprite.actionManager pauseTarget:sprite];

//resume
[sprite.actionManager resumeTarget:sprite];
```

This stopped the animation and kept the "paused" state even if the game is closed then reopened and I didn't even need to play with the AppDelegate class :). I hope this helps others too.

UPDATE: Just in case anybody else is creating a sprite using a loop, here's how I managed to create the pause and resume function for it:

```
[sprite.actionManager pauseAllRunningActions];
[sprite.actionManager resumeTargets:[NSSet setWithArray:spriteArray]];
```

note the difference between the two (resumeTarget and resumeTargets) then since resumeTargets would ask for NSSet, I simply passed the array objects into a NSSet with the above code.

Answer (score 2):

For this I would suggest you to manually control your sprites..
Make a method in main game scene which will pause your game.
You can pause sprites and animations using `pauseSchedulersAndActions` method on your sprite objects. And resume these actions in resumeMethod in your GameScene.

Call these method from your AppDelegate by getting reference of runningScene using CCDirector.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion but my sprites still moved. My animations in a normal method not a schedule so I call it like so: [self methodName] in the init method.

Comment: I was able to fix it after further research. I'll post what I did. Thank you for your help.